# Regex in NP++ to replace multiple queries with different ones

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I use Notepad++ to search and replace using regular expressions, and I need to replace more than one line with something else each..  Can I do that with **one command**?

Example:

```
"../../../commons/js/site-name.com__file-name.js"
"../dlds/file.css"
```

or

```
anytext "../../../commons/js/site-name.com__file-name.js" text
something "../dlds/file.css" anytext
```

or

```
<script src="../../../Folder/js/site-name.com__file-name.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/folder/file.css" />
```

output should be

```
"/resources/common.js"
"/resources/common.css"
```

Given that:

- The up dir ../ are changing (some are one ../ some more ../../../
  etc., so I need it to do that for any number of ../), or it could totally missing like: "/dlds/file.css".
- Those two lines
  in the example do not come exactly after each other, or at the
  beginning of text, but anywhere in the text.

Comment: Could  you clarify the question?  Is it filename.js or file-name.js?  Is it style.css or file.css?  Or are each valid?

Comment: So, all of the extra text is simply being removed to leave only the "/resources/common.js" or .css string?

Answer (score 1):

search for `^.+/(filename.js|style.css)"$`

Replace with `"/resources/$1"`

If you want to get any filename not just filename.js or style.css, use this

```
^.+\/(.+)(?!\/)"$
```

and use the same replacement.

Ex: http://rubular.com/r/h1IsZK8nry

Comment: thanks, it works only if they are in the start of the line, what if they could have text before or after them..  like I explained under the second point of the "Given that" above.

Comment: pattern `(.+?)\.\..+\/(.+)(?!\/)(.+)$` and replacement `$1/resources/$2$3` in that case

Comment: when I replace this (.+?).+/(filename.js|style.css)(.+)$ with "/resources/$1" it just replace the needed lines with "/resources/<" and it removes the whole line!

Comment: I did, but you missed my first point under the "Given that" that some lines could be without the ../ like "/dlds/style.css", so I used this (.+?).+/(filename.js|style.css)(.+)$ and replace it with $1/resources/$2$3, but it removes the start of the line

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/j1uxPn4NZK. Look at the matches, each match is represented by a number in that particular order.

Comment: the problem now is not with the matches, it is with the replace..  this $1/resources/$2$3 removes the start of the line

Comment: Do you mean the line breaks or text at the start of the lines?

Comment: sdfgdf "../dlds/style.css" xfgghdfs --- the previous line turns as: s/resources/style.css" xfgghdfs

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
\.\..+/([^\.]+\.\w+)
```

Replace:

```
/resources/\1
```

**Update:**

If you want to just replace filename.js or style.css find:

```
[\./]{1}.+/(filename.js|style.css)
```

replace with

```
/resources/\1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this finds anything in the document that has the ../  I just need to replace the exact /commons/js/filename.js or /dlds/style.css with the other lines below under the output

Comment: sorry, I thought you want to replace all occurrences of relative links to be absolute.

Comment: I checked your updated version, it works good, but not for files without the ../ like "/dlds/style.css"..  Another thing, can I change the output to be "/resources/new.js" and "/resources/new.css"?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

search for : `"(?:\.\./)+.*/([^.]+\.\w+)"`
replace with : `"/ressources/$1"`

if you want to replace with `new.js` or `new.css` do:

search for : `"(?:\.\./)+.*/[^.]+(\.\w+)"`
replace with : `"/ressources/new$1"`

for match also urls that begin with `/` :

search for : `"(?:(?:\.\./)+.*?)?/([^.]+\.\w+)"`
replace with : `"/ressources/new$1"`

Comment: thanks, this still doe find files without the ../ like "/dlds/style.css"..  Another thing, can I change the output to be "/resources/new.js" and "/resources/new.css"?

Comment: it still doesn't find files that doesn't have ../

Comment: I added a third example that is close to what I have..  given that the ../ are different or could be missing like "/folder/file.css"

Comment: this selects the whole two lines altogether, including what could be between them.. and also it matches other files than the two needed.

Comment: @Mike: just surround the regex with double quote.